# Cache post data for faster search queries on 5,000+ post site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, caching

I've been asked by a client to implement a new search feature in lieu of a custom Google search engine that kept displaying old results due to caching issues. Ironically, a solution to this question may result in a similar issue, but I'll deal with that when I get to it :).

The search code I've implemented is as follows:

```
<?php
global $query_string;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
  $query_split = explode("=", $string);
  $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$the_query = new WP_Query($search_query);
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
?>

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo esc_attr( $post->post_title ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This query is **super slow**. I know the current code runs a specific `WP_Query` based on the `$search_query`, but is there a way to cache the post data every so often to minimize queries to the database, and then compare search terms against those data?

Comment: 5000 posts isn't that much. What db engine are you using? Do you have proper indexes in your wp_posts table?

Comment: The `wp_posts` table (and most other default WordPress tables) uses MyISAM while most tables generated by various plugins use InnoDB. Regarding proper indexes, could you elaborate? `post_name`, `post_author`, and `post_parent` are present, but not `type_status_date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [WP_Object_Cache](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache).

Do something like:

```
global $query_string;

// Check the existing cache for this query
$post_ids = wp_cache_get( $query_string );

// If cache does not exist
if ( false === $post_ids ) {

    // Create the query
    $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
    $search_query = array();

    foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
      $query_split = explode("=", $string);
      $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
    }  

    //This is the super slow query.
    $the_query = new WP_Query($search_query);

    //Grab the ID:s so we can make a much more lightweight query later
    $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $the_query->posts, 'ID' );

    //Cache it!
    wp_cache_set($query_string, $post_ids);

    $posts = $the_query->posts;
} else {
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post__in' => $post_ids,
    ));

    while($the_query->have_posts()) {
        // loop here
    }
}
```

This will get the query string as you were previously then save that query string to the WP Object Cache. We check for that query string in the cache, if it is not found then we run the query and save the results, if it is found, loop through the posts.

The queries will run slow the first time they are ran, but will speed up as they are cached.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of `wp_list_pluck`. But I'm guessing this approach won't recognize new posts that include an already-cached query string? As yivi touched upon, I'm wondering if the database is simply poorly optimized (though they do use the "Optimize DB" plugin).

Comment: You could fairly easily modify the above code to detect new posts on publish and index them if you need